# Bubble sort vs Insertion sort run-time

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort, insertion-sort

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the run-time of a bubble sort vs an insertion sort. It takes in two inputs, number of elements and elements, and calculates their run-time. This is what I have so far, but it is printing the same time for both sorters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

int bubblesort(int a[], int n);
int insertionsort(int a[], int n);

int main()
{
    int s,temp,i,j,comparisons,a[20];
    float function_time;
    clock_t start;
    clock_t end;
    printf("Enter total numbers of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&s);
    printf("Enter %d elements: ",s);

    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);

  //Bubble sorting algorithm

    for(i=s-2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
                temp=a[j];

                a[j]=a[j+1];

                a[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    a[i]= rand()%10000;

    start = clock();    
    comparisons= bubblesort(a, s);
    end = clock();
    function_time = (float)(end)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);  // Time in seconds
    printf("\nTime for Bubble Sort is %f microseconds\n ", function_time);

    // Insertion sorting algorithm

    for(i=1;i<s;i++)
    {
        temp=a[i];
        j=i-1;
        while((temp<a[j])&&(j>=0))
        {
            a[j+1]=a[j];
            j=j-1;
        }
        a[j+1]=temp;
    }

    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    a[i]= rand()%10000;

    start = clock();    
    comparisons= insertionsort(a, s);
    end = clock();
    function_time = (float)(end)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);  // Time in seconds
    printf("\nTime for Insertion Sort is %f microseconds\n ", function_time);

    return 0;
}

int bubblesort(int a[], int n)
{
    bool swapped = false;
    int temp=0, counter=0;

    for (int j = n-1; j>0; j--)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int k = 0; k<j; k++) 
            {
                counter++;
                if (a[k+1] < a[k]) 
                {
                    temp= a[k];
                    a[k] = a[k+1];
                    a[k+1]= temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        if (!swapped)
            break;
    }

return counter;
}

int insertionsort(int a[], int n)
{
    bool swapped = false;
    int temp=0, counter=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {    
        for (int s=i; s>0; s--)
        {
            counter++;
            if (a[s]<a[s-1])
            {
                temp=a[s-1];
                a[s-1]=a[s];
                a[s]=temp;
                swapped = true;
            } 
        }
        if (!swapped)
            break;
    }
return counter;
}
```

Comment: I think your code is redundant. The code for both the sorts are repeated twice. Why?

Comment: Not sure how to change this or where to begin.

Comment: `clock` is not a suitable method of measuring runtime. That's your main problem. The resolution is too poor, and on many systems it doesn't even work as documented.

Comment: You need big data sets to compare using `clock()` — try 10k to 50k in 10k increments, for example.  You also need to make sure you are sorting the same data with each algorithm. Create the data by any mechanism you choose, then make a copy of it; then sort one copy with bubble sort and the other with insertion sort, timing them.

Comment: Aside from the fact that `clock` is a poor choice of timing methods, in order to measure the performance of something like sorting algorithms you need to sort huge numbers of elements.  Think in terms of 100s of thousands or even millions of elements, not just a few things a user can type in.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the way you calculate the sorting time is wrong:

```
function_time = (float)(end)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

It should be:

```
function_time = (float)(end-start)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Secondly, although bubble sort and insertion sort both have O(n square) complexity, time taken  should have some difference, they cannot be the same. If the problem persists, you should check the output of clock() function, it may not work in your system.

Edit: I found that your code let user type in the elements manually. So I guess your array can only be relatively small. Sorting small-size array takes very little time so the difference is hard to notice. You should let the elements assigned randomly by code, so that you can generate large array for analysis.